# How to add incrementation to a variable as often as another one surpasses a certain value?

Tags: java, eclipse, increment

I am coding a program for myself, for learning java. It is some kind of experiment. It has classes like player, actions, monsters, items, gameplay. In my class player, i added a constructor which i called lvlUp with the parameter exp. My question is, what do I have to write when I want to increment the lvl of a player when he reaches 100 exp, 200 exp, 300 exp etc. When he has 100 exp, he gets one level up, when he has 200 exp, he gets 2 lvl ups, etc. . Btw, the exp is random, so I would like to print out the remaining exp as well. For example, he kills one monster and earns 245 exp, that should be 2 lvl ups and 45 exp. this is my code atm:

```
public int lvlUp(int exp) {
    if (exp < 100) {
        System.out.println("LvL: " + this.lvl + " You have " + exp + " experience!");
    } else if (exp == 100) {
        System.out.println("Level up !!!");
        exp = 0;
        this.lvl++;
    } else if (exp > 100) {
        System.out.println("Level up !!!");
        exp = exp - 100;
        this.lvl++;
        System.out.println("LvL: " + this.lvl + " You have " + exp + " experience!");
    }
    return this.lvl++;
```

Comment: this piece of code only works when exp is < 200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to figure out how many level ups the player should get. To calculate that, divide by 100.

```
int levels = exp / 100;
```

Since that's integer arithmetic, it will truncate for you. (So in your example of `exp = 245`, level will be 2.

Next, use that value to figure out how much experience the user has left over.

```
exp = exp - (levels * 100);
```

Finally, add the new levels.

```
this.lvl += levels;
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess this would do the job

```
// your class code
int exp = 0;
int lvl = 0;
// ...

public int lvlUp(int exp){  // increase the experience by exp and update the level
    this.exp += exp;
    lvl = exp / 100;  // integer division
    System.out.println("Levels: " + lvl + ", experience left: " + exp % 100);
    return lvl;
}
```

Comment: what should i add in order to get the exp, like for example if i have 234 exp. lvl would be 2 and i want exp to be 34.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have global variable like the lvlBar. This will serve as the level counter for the player to see their experience that is needed to level up.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, i will add that variable into my project :)